# How to add last column attribute where it should be when using a basic CSS responsive grid

Tags: html, css, grid, media-queries, responsive

I'm struggling with some basic HTML / CSS here.
I have a simple `ul` within an html container. The list itself has 6 `li` elements.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Interests</h2>
  <ul class="interests-list">
    <li class="interest m-all t-1of6 d-1of6"><img src="camping.png"></li>
    <li class="interest m-all t-1of6 d-1of6"><img src="hiking.png"></li>
    <li class="interest m-all t-1of6 d-1of6"><img src="biking.png"></li>
    <li class="interest m-all t-1of6 d-1of6"><img src="diy.png"></li>
    <li class="interest m-all t-1of6 d-1of6"><img src="reading.png"></li>
    <li class="interest m-all t-1of6 d-1of6 last-col"><img src="coffee.png"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Class names here reference my simple css grid which looks like this :

```
@mixin grid-col {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 0.75em;
}

.last-col {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .m-all {
    @include grid-col;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .m-1of2 {
    @include grid-col;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1029px) {
  .t-all {
    @include grid-col;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .t-1of2 {
    @include grid-col;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1030px) {
  .d-all  {
    @include grid-col;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .d-1of2 {
    @include grid-col;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .d-1of6 {
    @include grid-col;
    width: 16.6666666667%;
  }
}
```

The sixth element in my case is the **last column** when browsed from a **desktop screen**, but **what happens when media queries are called and layout is modified?**

Where do I have to add the `last-col` class in order for it to be in the right place for each media query?

Does my simple grid lack something important?

Is my logic flawed?

Do I have to bring in some Javascript / jQuery to dynamically "tag" the last column?

**EDIT**

Here is a CodePen of my issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrONMo

Comment: You should look into `nth-child` selector. Based on your media query you can set your 2nd/3rd or nth element to be last. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child

Comment: i don't understand why you even care which element is the last element?

Comment: I wouldn't ask if I didn't care ; and I care so I can remove my `padding-right` on each last column item (n. b. - padding is from my `grid-col` mixin). Maybe my logic is flawed in which case I'd really appreciate a bit of help :)